# How to store proxy credentials on macOS so they are used by system services?

Tags: macos, network, keychain, proxy

I'm using macOS Sierra 10.12.6 behind a corporate NTLM proxy. My browser and other applications are using the system proxy settings, in which I have saved my username and password for authenticating with the proxy. This is working fine.

There is a persistent problem with system services that try to access information on the internet and don't see to have access to the proxy credentials in my user account. I see the following popup every couple of minutes, and whatever I do (updating my credentials in System Preferences, or pressing "Not Now"), the popup keeps coming up again and again:

[image: Proxy Authentication Required]

The text in the popup reads:

> Proxy Authentication Required
>
> Enter the password for the HTTP proxy http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:yyyy in System Preferences.

What can I do to stop this popup from appearing?

Things I have tried so far:

- Updated my credentials in System Preferences (*Network > Advanced > Proxy*)
- Copied the credentials entries from my *login* keychain to the *System* keychain, since I read a recommendation for that in a blog post or forum question.

None of these has worked, I get this popup every couple of minutes, and there does not seem to be a pattern to when it shows up.

**Update 1:**

As soon as I enter my credentials by clicking the *System Preferences* button in the above dialog (which I can force by e.g. opening Safari and starting to type a URL in the location box), *two* records are created in the *login* keychain, both with identical content:

> @ xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx (username)    Internet Password     Today, 09:10    --    login

Both records look identical, with the same name and attributes. Both show that the application that requested this is `AuthBrokerAgent`:

[image: Keychain Access Control]

**Update 2:**

I've also tried this suggestion: https://discussions.apple.com/message/23848961#message23848961, copying the authentication entries from the *login* keychain to the *system* keychain and then rebooting, but it did not fix it. In fact, the dreaded "Proxy Authentication Required" box showed up again while typing this...

**Update 3:**

I've used Wireshark to take a look at the traffic between my machine and our proxy:

- The proxy returns with a `407 Proxy Authentication Required` and `Proxy-Authenticate: NTLM`, which is in line with my expectation, since our proxy uses NTLM.
- Some examples I've seen in the traffic (e.g. iCloud) then send back an `NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE` response.
- The proxy comes back with an `NTLMSSP_CHALLENGE` request
- The service responds with `NTLMSSP_AUTH` and my username, which it must have gotten from somewhere.
- The proxy finally responds with a `200 Connection established`

To me, this shows that in general the proxy authentication works fine, if the system can get the username and proxy from somewhere. The question remains how/where to store the username/password so that all system services can find it. Some system services (I assume) don't have any means to find the proxy credentials where I'm currently storing them.

Comment: Related question: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/117556/proxy-login-popups-on-mavericks

Comment: What proxy are you using?  I remember (from a different past life) that a proxy we were using had the ability to disallow storing of passwords thereby **forcing** the user to authenticate each and every time.  This could be the case.

Comment: Did you ever resolve this issue because I encounter the same problem occasionally and I'm connecting to a Citrix VPN solution. Once the pop-up appears it just happens over and over again and eventually my AD account will lock up. I have yet to find a solution that resolves this. Since I'm using a MacBook Pro and the majority of the IT Department is Windows based I have been unable to receive any useful information from IT. Once I do connect to the VPN I'm working on Oracle applications running on Solaris SPARC servers. I really hope you find a way to resolve this issue. stan

Comment: Sorry, have not found a solution for this yet. What I end up doing is that I move the window that asks for the proxy credentials to the side of the screen without pressing any of the buttons - that keeps it quiet at least...

Comment: In my case also two almost the same items appears in the login keychain but there is a one small difference - one of them is for HTTP protocol and second one for HTTPS.

Answer (score 9):

This is most likely expected behavior if your system/network administrator has configured the proxy force authentication that requires more than just a basic authentication scheme.

From Microsoft's page [Handling Authentication](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384220%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) under *About HTTP Authentication* section:

> There are two general types of authentication schemes:
>
> - Basic authentication scheme, where the user name and password are sent in
>   cleartext to the server.
> - Challenge-response schemes, which allow for a
>   challenge-response format.
>
> Challenge-response schemes enable more secure authentication. If a
> request requires authentication using a challenge-response scheme, the
> appropriate status code and Authenticate headers are returned to the
> client. The client must then to resend the request with a negotiate.
> The server would return an appropriate status code with a challenge,
> and the client would then require to resend the request with the
> proper response to get the requested service.

If the proxy you are using utilizes the *basic authentication* scheme, what's saved in your keychain will suffice to authenticate you.  If a *challenge response* scheme is being used, you will most likely have to provide more info - in this case - re-enter your password - to authenticate; and this is what you are seeing.

#### NTLM Authentication Process

This is much more than just *storing* credentials.  The client must *generate* a response based upon a *generated* request from the server.  Following is a *very abridged* description of the authentication process from the client/server perspective per  [Microsoft's documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa378749(v=vs.85).aspx)

> - The client sends the user name to the server (in plaintext).
> - The server generates a 16-byte random number, called a challenge or nonce, and sends it to the client.
> - The client encrypts this challenge with the hash of the user's password and returns the result to the server. This is called the
>   response.
> - The server sends the following three items to the domain controller:
>
>   - User name
>   - Challenge sent to the client
>   - Response received from the client
> - The DC validates the encrypted challenge and response.  If authenticated, access is granted.

The third step above, ***requires** the client to hash a random number it got from the server.*  This inherently means there's nothing to be stored on your macOS client.

At a very minimum, you need to be joined the Active Directory domain.  This means you need [Kerberos](https://opensource.apple.com/source/Kerberos/Kerberos-62/KerberosClients/KerberosApp/Documentation/using-osx.html?f=text) support enabled and configured properly for your specific organization.

There's a key phrase in the "Handling Authentication" document I linked above:

> If authentication is required, the INTERNET_FLAG_KEEP_CONNECTION flag
> should be used in the call to HttpOpenRequest. The
> INTERNET_FLAG_KEEP_CONNECTION flag is required for NTLM and other
> types of authentication in order to maintain the connection while
> completing the authentication process. **If the connection is not
> maintained, the authentication process must be restarted with the
> proxy or server.**

<sup>(Emphasis mine)</sup>

Based on your the symptoms being presented it appears that your organization requires authentication to the proxy; your username/password are valid, but it keeps (re)asking for authentication.  It's probably because you are losing the connection state and having to do this all over again.  Which further emphasizes the point....

**To solve this issue, you will need to contact your network admin to assist you with the authentication issues.**

Comment: How can I find out which authentication scheme is being used? Is there an HTTP header that I could look at when an application is talking to the proxy? Can I do this in Chrome's network console, or do I have to use something like Wireshark?

Comment: More than likely, you would need to use Wireshark.  Keep in mind, it may also be encrypted traffic.

Comment: I've added some info from what I've seen in Wireshark to the question.

Comment: Thanks for adding more info on NTLM to your answer. I understand NTLM, and from what I can see from the Wireshark output, it is working - the challenge/response you describe is being done, e.g. for Dropbox or iCloud services. I'm still not sure which service is popping up the repeated proxy credential dialogs. Your answer contains a lot of info, but does not really help me so far.

Comment: `Connection Established` != `Access Granted`.  The people who can *confirm* that this is working is your system/network admin(s) in your IT department.

Answer (score 4):

[image: Note: check radio button to allow all application to use proxy]

by authention of  key chain app  modify setting

Comment: It works for me for a while (few minutes) and then this setting is automatically switched back to "Confirm before allowing access" and applications starts to show popups again. I have a suspicion that the item is removed and recreated again with some default options. Not sure which application do this and why.

Answer (score -3):

Run the following command from `Console.app`:

```
networksetup -setwebproxy "Your Interface Name" "web proxy hostname or IP" 
8080 on username password
```

You will be asked about keychain access. Agree to add the record into keychain and you will have an access without the password all the time when your keychain is *open.*

Comment: I've tried this, but it does not fix the issue. The command sets the proxy config for my user, and stores the authentication in my user's `login` keychain. Right after I did this, the proxy authentication dialog I show above popped up again. Your suggested fix does not fix the issue for me.

Comment: because your login keychain is locked or you have double records

Comment: The login keychain is unlocked, I double-checked that. The point about double records might be valid, though. I deleted all records for the proxy authentication that I found in the login and system keychains, but as soon as I type in my password once in the dialog in my original post, I end up with two records in the login keychain, both with exactly the same data. If I delete one, it comes back when I enter my credentials again.

Comment: Do you have a wireshark installed? Could you please dump all negotiations between your osx and proxy server and a keychain records (security find-generic-password -g -s your_proxy_definition)? I have strong feeling that proxy authentification appears by https, not by http. Did you tried to define your proxy url as https?

Comment: I tried the `security` command you listed - it does not find anything. It does if  I change the `find-generic-password` command to `find-internet-password`, since the Keychain lists the entry as of kind "Internet password".

Comment: The proxy URL is set up as http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx, that's the way it's been working e.g. from command line. I'll try to capture something using Wireshark.

Comment: I've added some info from what I've seen in Wireshark to the question.

Comment: Looks like it was similar bug in 10.10

Comment: Looks like it was similar bug in 10.10 https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1785?locale=en_US. So, did you tried f.e use Firefox proxy settings, behaviour is different? (you can use systemwide proxy and manually enter proxy settings there

Comment: Tried Firefox, no change...

Comment: Both variants, systemwide proxy in Firefox and internal Firefox settings for http proxy?

Comment: Yes, both - neither did work.